# Access denied cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: c#, phpmyadmin

I'm using C# and SQL for this one and when I start to use phpMyAdmin, I get the error down below. I'm trying to replicate [this project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDNA9VYyOME&t=1517s) by the way.

[image: Error]

Comment: That's a video, not a project.

Comment: BTW you don't need `phpAdmin` to create a .NET web app. You can't compress an "entire C# course" into just 6 hours, especially when some of them are wasted installing things like phpAdmin. Microsoft's site contains a *lot* of courses, tutorials, how-to's and step-by-step examples. You can sign up to the (free) [Visual Studio Dev Essentials](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/dev-essentials/) program to get access to some of the best third-party .NET courses

Comment: In learn.microsoft.com, check the [ASP.NET Core Getting Started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows) tutorial and the courses in [Learn ASP.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet).